# Change the default installation path of SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, path, installation, ssms

Can I change the default installation path when installing ***SQL Server Management Studio*** that is **C:**?

My C: drive is full as it has system applications and I want to install SQL Server Management Studio in **D:** drive. Is this possible?

Answer (score 16):

There is no direct approach (At last now) to change the default SQL Server Management Studio installation path **but** you can use **Symbolic Links**:

### What are Symbolic Links?

From [The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) :

> Symbolic links are basically advanced shortcuts. Create a symbolic link to an individual file or folder, and that link will appear to be the same as the file or folder to Windows even though it’s just a link pointing at the file or folder.

#### Windows 10 users

Windows 10 users must first enable Developer Mode from

> Settings > Update & Security > For Developers.

### How To

1. Open `Command Prompt` or `Windows PowerShell` with **Run as Administrator** and paste this command before installing SQL Server Management Studio

> ```
> mkdir "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
> mkdir "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> mklink /J "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
> mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"
> ```

2. Now install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

> There may be some other file and folder in drive `C` like
>   `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server` but they aren't bigger
>   than 1GB.

#### What if already installed SSMS?

Close all instance of SSMS and rename these folders to anything you wish:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Follow **How To** steps and move the contents of the folders (cut/paste) to the new location

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked with my problem: fatal error during installation 0x80070643

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible starting from SSMS 18.0.

> **[SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.0 released for general availability](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/04/24/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-0-released-for-general-availability/)**
>
> **SSMS can be installed in a custom folder** – This has been a long standing request. With SSMS 18, you can install SSMS in any folder and the option is available from both command line and the setup UI.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the info. It sure will help others as it immensely helped me when I was installing `Ver 18.0`.

Comment: Latest version, 18.4, absolutely refuses to give me this ability. I'm stuck with C: and that's it.  Annoying.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Interesting, so it is a regression. Did you uninstall the previous version of SSMS first?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I didn't because I had a fair number of connections setup on that installation.

Comment: I put in E: drive into the installer, and yet it still installed over 1800MB on my C drive. VERY unhappy.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this need updating registry value with use of powershell script and then running the installation, Post installation registry values are reset to default

## Update the Value of default installation Directory

```
$RegKey =”HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion”
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir” -Value “D:\Program Files”
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir (x86)” -Value ‘D:\Program Files (x86)’
Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir”
Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir (x86)”
Write-Host “1. Run the SSMS installer and wait for its completion… (Start-Process -Wait)” -ForegroundColor Yellow
$process=”D:\Software\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe”
$args=”/install”
Start-Process $process -ArgumentList $args -Wait
Write-Host “`nProcess `”$process`” has been executed and is now stopped.” -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
```

## Revert the Value to default installation Directory

```
$RegKey =”HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion”
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir” -Value “C:\Program Files”
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir (x86)” -Value ‘C:\Program Files (x86)’
Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir”
Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name “ProgramFilesDir (x86)”
```

update the location of icons in start menu to the updated location of the SSMS file.

In my case I had to browse to

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server Tools 17
```

Right click on SSMS and update the target to the new location of SSMS program files and you are all set to go. For detailed instructions 
https://sqlx86.com/2018/06/28/installing-ssms-to-a-different-location/

Comment: Almost a working solution. Had to manually rewrite the Start-Process $process -ArgumentList $args -Wait , as the args were passed as null. Don't know the reason.

Answer (score 3):

I have earlier given an answer to this post to do this using powershell by editing registry values.

Since then I have tried different things and here I am again with a new way to install SQL Server management Studio from command line to an user desired path.

Steps to do so are as follows

1. Download latest version of SSMS from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Press Win+Q key to open search on your computer and type in cmd, Cick on Run as administrator on the right hand side pane.
3. Browse to recently downloaded SSMS media from URL in step 1, In my case it was in D:\Software
4. Use below command to install it to a different folder, In my case I am installing it on D:\test.

“SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /Install /quiet /norestart /log D:\Test\log.txt SSMSInstallRoot = D:\test”

And you are all set…

For instructions with screenshot do visit 
https://sqlx86.com/2018/12/27/change-the-default-installation-path-for-sql-server-management-studio-using-command-prompt/

Comment: Didn't work for me with 17.9.1...still install in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction given on microsoft support https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

I repaired the Visual Studio 2015 IsoShell and its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 18.8 version (latest) and presto!

[image: Nice!]

Comment: This looked like it worked but in settings > apps & features it still shows it is taking up 2.64GB on the C drive.