# Unable to change SQL Server Management Studio installation path

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, installation

I installed SSMS on an external storage by mistake. Then I uninstalled it and also removed associated files from the directory of my primary drive.

But now I am unable to change the default path of installation to the `C:` drive.

[image: here is my installation wizard.]

Comment: Is your directory *really* called "progams"? Also, is the folder you want to install the application really called "SQLSeverManagementStudio"?

Comment: There a topic for this issue. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490699/change-the-default-installation-path-of-sql-server-management-studio Gl.

Comment: i made a mistake by installing it on my external hard drive. but it doesnt work
now i want to install it on internal drive but i cant edit this path

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue like you.
I installed SSMS in a disk name `D:\`. But I changed the name of this disk to `K:\` after that.
So I cannot install the new version of SSMS anymore because it get `D:\` as the root location in Registry

#### Solution

You can try to edit variable `SSMSInstallRoot` in Registry

**Step 1**: Open Registry Editor

**Step 2**: Go to this folder in Registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio\19`

In my situation, the version of SSMS is 19, so I go to 19 folder, If you install another version, go to this version instead.

You can see an example in the image below.
[image: The folder show variables of 19 folder]

**Step 3**: Double click on the variable name `SSMSInstallRoot` then change the location to the one you want.

[image: Edit String box to edit location for install SSMS]

Finnaly, Install your software.

#### References

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/502847/ssms-invalid-location-please